# Syntax missing operator SQL insert in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a "SYNTAX MISSING OPERATOR" error in Visual Basic.

This is my code:

```
 cmd.Connection = conn
 'add data to the database

 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [STUDENT REGISTRATION REPORT]([StudentID],[FirstName],[LastName],[Course],[YearLevel],[Department],[Age],[Gender],[Cleaning],[CavityFilling],[Xray],[Flouride],[RootCanal])" & _
 "VALUES(" & studentid.Text & "','" & firstname.Text & "','" & lastname.Text & "','" & course.Text & "','" & yearlevel.Text & "','" & department.Text & "','" & _ age.Text & "','" & gender.Text & "','" & cleaning.Checked & "','" & cavityfilling.Checked & "','" & xray.Checked & "','" & flouride.Checked & "','" & _
                      rootcanal.Checked & "')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'close connection

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Use SQL parameters. That in itself fixes a lot of syntax issues aswell as improving security.

Comment: There is usually more to the Exception message.  But always use SQL Parameters.  That has not been the right way to compose SQL for many years.

Comment: As well as using SQL parameters, you should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to make sure all the variable types match up. However, that will not tell you the correct spelling of *fluoride*.

Comment: Perhaps a linebreak is missing at `& _ age.Text &`? Or remove the underscore?

Comment: title needed to be more specific